# ERROR 1054 mySQL and Log function

Tags: mysql

I'm getting this error when I input this query:

```
SELECT E.event, 
       ED.location, 
       ED.doe, 
       ED.category, 
       ( ( ED.numofdataset / ED.numoftimesloc ) * 100 )                    AS 
       LOGLOC, 
       ( ( ED.numofdataset / ED.numoftimesdoe ) * 100 )                    AS 
       LOGDOE, 
       ( ( ED.numofdataset / ED.numoftimescat ) * 100 )                    AS 
       LOGCAT, 
       (( ( ED.numoftimesloc * ( Log(logloc) ) ) + 
           ( ED.numoftimesdoe * ( Log(logdoe) ) ) + ( ED.numoftimescat * 
                                                      ( Log(logcat) ) ) )) AS 
       FINALRANK 
FROM   event E, 
       eventdetail ED 
WHERE  E.eventid = ED.eventid 
       AND ED.location = 'LONDON' 
       AND ED.category = 'Sports' 
ORDER  BY finalrank DESC;
```

The command controller tells me that 'LOGLOC' is an Unknown  column in the 'field list'.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and also if my use of the LOG() function is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't perform calculations on an aliased column.

Try this:

```
SELECT f.event, 
       f.location, 
       f.doe, 
       f.category, 
       f.logloc, 
       f.logdoe, 
       f.logcat, 
       (( ( f.numoftimesloc * ( Log(f.logloc) ) ) + 
             ( f.numoftimesdoe * ( Log(f.logdoe) ) ) + ( 
           f.numoftimescat * ( Log(f.logcat) ) ) )) AS FINALRANK 
FROM   (SELECT E.event, 
               ED.location, 
               ED.doe, 
               ED.category, 
               ( ( ED.numofdataset / ED.numoftimesloc ) * 100 ) AS LOGLOC, 
               ( ( ED.numofdataset / ED.numoftimesdoe ) * 100 ) AS LOGDOE, 
               ( ( ED.numofdataset / ED.numoftimescat ) * 100 ) AS LOGCAT, 
               ed.numoftimesloc, 
               ed.numoftimesdoe, 
               ed.numoftimescat 
        FROM   event E, 
               eventdetail ED 
        WHERE  E.eventid = ED.eventid 
               AND ED.location = 'LONDON' 
               AND ED.category = 'Sports' 
        ORDER  BY finalrank DESC) f
```

Comment: Oh is there a way around it?

Comment: @crunchynutter See my update. It should give you the basic idea.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I've used your update and changed my query but now its giving me the same error but this time it says Unknown column 'finalrank' in 'order clause'.

Comment: @crunchynutter Move it to the outside.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk It's given me another error where it says every table must have its own alias.

Comment: @crunchynutter Then you missed the `f`.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk nope I put the 'f' in aswel

Answer (score 0):

It's not a known column because it's not on the table.  You're creating an alias for it here:

```
((ED.numofdataset / ED.numoftimesloc) * 100) AS LOGLOC
```

However, alias columns can't be referenced elsewhere in the `SELECT` clause.  (Think of it like they don't actually exist until after that clause has been parsed.  So they can be used in certain other clauses, such as `ORDER BY`, because that's operating on the results of the `SELECT` whereas the `SELECT` is operating on the table(s).)

There may be some SQL tricks of which I'm unaware to reduce the code duplication, but otherwise you might just have to run the calculation directly:

```
Log((ED.numofdataset / ED.numoftimesloc) * 100)
```